# Sharing Eclipse projects on a dual boot system

Tags: windows, eclipse, svn, ubuntu, workspace

I recently converted my laptop to a Ubuntu/Win7 dual boot system, each with their own partitions, plus a third shared partition.  I'd like to use Eclipse and access my SVN repository regardless which system I'm booted into at the time.

If I have my local SVN repository on the shared partition, how can I enable the workspaces on both Ubuntu and Windows to the files?

The only other alternative I've come up with is to have each OS have their own working copy, and apply commits and updates as necessary.

**Edit for clarification**

I'm not asking if its possible to have a single workspace for both Linux and Windows.  I had in mind a single source folder in the shared partition that was linked to each workspace.  Therefore, the file paths would be OS-specific, and only the source code would be accessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is really possible.

There are a number of files in the workspace `.metadata` folder (for instance the definition of the JRE/JDKs or the eclipse path) that will be dependent on the underlying file system (e.g. `c:\eclipse` for Windows on one side and `/home/me/eclipse`.

What you might be able to do at best is two different workspaces, one for windows and one for Linux.

These two distinct workspaces, in turn would be sharing a number of project.  These projects would not be in the so-called `default location`  (that is under the `workspace` folder location) of any of these two workspaces but under a separate hierarchy under your shared partition.  Yet because of these decoupling you would end up doing several things twice (such as defining launch configurations etc...).  Which is fair enough I guess.

Finally, since Linux can read ntfs file systems pretty well (to the exception of ACLs which would actually be a plus) using ntfs3g, you can have your shared partition in NTFS.  Windows is less apt at reading/writing ext3fs (let alone ext4fs).  Just make sure you mount your NTFS partition with a common character set.

In addition, instead of having a dual boot, you could have Windows run inside a VM (e.g. VirtualBox and share the common data as a linux shared folder either through standard Samba or VirtualBox built-in shared folder mechanism.  The difference with a dual boot would be that you could in theory cheat eclipse and access your 2 different workspaces simultaneously yet they would share the same projects.  Of course this would require some tweaking from the Samba part for locking management.

Comment: I edited my question to state more clearly what I am looking for.  The shared partition is already set up as NTFS, and it works just fine.  I tried using a VM (and use it on my desktop), but this is a laptop, and I noticed severe system slowdowns using both Virtualbox and VMware Player.  Apparently the laptop CPU lacks hardware virtualization, and performance degradation is very noticeable as compared to when booting straight.

Comment: You're right you need 4GB at least for desktop virtualization.  One more note, VMware does not use a lot hardware virtualization, they are still AFAIK mainly in a binary translation mode.  Also for VT-x, for obscure money reasons, some laptop OEM disable VT-x (they got rebates from Intel if they do) and you have to patch the BIOS (providing the CPU supports HW VT).

Comment: Then I believe it would be possible.  Because the projects themselves are fairly portable. This is why you can export and import them as zip files accross one os to the other.

Comment: The approach of sharing projects might work. You need to understand how SVN handles character encoding and line breaks. Many source control system will adjust these on the way in and out (see my answer). If SVN doesn't do this or you can configure it not to, it may be safe to share your project directories between operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend sharing the same Eclipse workspace between two operating systems as they use different path syntax. You can also run into character encoding and/or line separators issues in files placed into source control. Typically a source control system will do adjustments to these during "check out" and reverse adjustment on "check in". You can have weird problems if you retrieve code in Windows and check it back in on Linux (or the other way around).

I would recommend keeping your Windows and Linux workspaces separate.

Comment: OK, I was hoping to avoid this, since it requires having two local working copies.